# How update own package npm

Tags: node.js, npm, publish

I'm trying to update my own package using npm, I want to update from the 1.0 to 1.1.

I tried to run npm publish my-package and it was ok, the console told me it was 1.0 but on the website it's still 1.0 and I can't update other project to 1.1, the version doesn't exists.

There is something to do more than just npm-publish?

Comment: Did you edit the [`"version"`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#version) in its `package.json` to `"1.1.0"`?

Comment: Yes I did, else I wouldn't have seen 1.1.0 in the shell.

Comment: Then, typo? "*console told me it was 1.0*"

Comment: No, it actually was 1.0.0 not 1.0 and it's 1.1.0 now in the package.json, I just did it again using --force command and it's updated on npmjs.com now... I don't know what happened, maybe it takes time?

Comment: It can take some time for the version to appear to be updated on the website. Possibly something to do with caching.